# Java Mail SMTP authentication requirement check without sending a mail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I want to know that how can we check if an SMTP server requires authentication or not without sending an email. I am getting the **SMTPSendFailedException** on **Transport.send(mimemessage)**
which further says that "Must issue a STARTTLS command first" but I don't want to use any authentication method.

Is there any way to check whether authentication is required or not without actually sending an email.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> "Must issue a STARTTLS command first"

That is not a request to authenticate.  The STARTTLS command is the start of the protocol for negotiating a secure connection with the server.  If the server *requires* you to negotiate a secure connection to talk to it (on the port that you have selected), then you must do that.

This has to happen before the server will request any requests ...

> Is there any way to check whether authentication is required or not without actually sending an email.

According to the SMTP spec, certain commands (VRFY, EXPN) may be requested without authenticating, but:

- The spec says that the client *should* start with an EHLO to tell the server who it is.
- A server would be within its rights to refuse VRFY or EXPN requests, whether or not the client has identified itself with an EHLO or authenticated itself (somehow).

I don't think there is a reliable way to test if the server requires a client / user to authenticate ... in the correct sense of that word ... without trying to send an email.